# Implement search query in H2 database with multiple optional parameters

Tags: database, rest, spring-boot, h2, spring-restcontroller

Am new to

> Spring boot and H2 database

. I have to write rest controllers which does search functionality.
To search there are  multiple optional attributes as search parameters. 
How should i design my endpoint and how should i design my query. There are 5 search parameters and i can't have all permutation and combinations for search query right? 
Similarly can't have end points for all combination of search parameters.
How should i design my solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint should accept these parameters(i.e. as query strings). You will have to build the query dynamically.

You can use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/), check out the docs.

Here's a snippet from my project where two params are optional:

```
QBkAddress bkAddress = QBkAddress.bkAddress;
BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
if(bkOrganizationId != null) {
    where.and(bkAddress.bkOrganization.id.eq(bkOrganizationId));
}
if(bkCityId != null) {
    where.and(bkAddress.bkCity.id.eq(bkCityId));
}
Iterable<BkAddress> iterable = bkAddressRepository.findAll(where);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Example` provided by spring-data for optional search query. Here is a example,

```
 Class User{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String id;
  }

  Class UserService{
     // All are optional
     List<User> findBy(String firstName, String lastName, String id){
        User u = new User();
        u.setFirstName(firstName);
        u.setLastName(lastName);
        u.setId(id);

        userRepository.findAll(Example.of(user));
        // userRepository is a JpaRepository class
     }
  }
```